# Does vim 8 have some screensaver-like mechanism

Tags: vim8

I'm working with Vim 8 on the system Ubuntu and I'm thinking if Vim has some mechanism, which is just like the screensaver in Windows.

In a word, I'm trying to do a kind of configuration for my Vim, which is:

if user keeps afk (no typing any key from keyboard) for a while, some job managed by the `timer` mechanism of Vim 8 will be executed.

I've known how `timer_start` and `timer_stop` worked, but I don't know whether Vim could detect afk or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To detect afk you can use `CursorHold` and `CursorHoldI` events.

If you want to run it once:

```
augroup afk | au!
    autocmd CursorHold,CursorHoldI * ++once echo "Run my timer here"
augroup END
```

Or everytime user is AFK :

```
augroup afk | au!
    autocmd CursorHold,CursorHoldI * echo "Run my timer here"
augroup END
```

Both events are fired after `updatetime` period of inactivity (default 4 seconds).